# Incorrect php syntax, or improper usage? Customizing headers in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I've added this to my header and nothing is printed in the corresponding page id's header! What am I doing wrong??

```
<?php
if ( is_page(66) )  {
   echo '<link rel="stylesheet" href="/mobileshop.css">';
}
?>
```

Comment: Is that `if` statement being satisfied? Your question is lacking alot of information.

Comment: No, checked the header of page id 66 and this code DNE! :(

Comment: When you say you 'added to my header', what do you mean? Are you adding it into `header.php` or are you passing it in via a `wp_head` action?

Comment: Added it to header.php

Comment: @rootsup are you manipulating the main query in any way beforehand? it might be useful to see a bit of the surrounding code.

Comment: I'm not, it's the typical header file of the theme - lots of stuff going on. Just throwing this in at the end of the header. I think part of the issue has to do with "only being able to use conditional query tags after the posts_selection" which I grazed over too fast. Trying to figure how to incorporate it into a WP_Query conditional ask

Answer (score 1):

This kind of logic shouldn't go in *header.php*. Rather, you should be adding it to *functions.php* and attaching it to the proper action hook:

```
function so_34643502_conditional_styles() {
    if ( is_page(66) )  {
        // Make sure to edit the src path to match how your theme is set up
        wp_enqueue_style('mobileshop', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . 'mobileshop.css');
    }
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'so_34643502_conditional_styles');
```

Read more about [`wp_enqueue_style`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style) and [`wp_enqueue_scripts`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_enqueue_scripts) in the Codex.

Answer (score -1):

Couldn't get it to work via standard pages, woocommerce plugin was hijacking the theme so I ended up editing the woocommerce theme templates.